# Combined Exceptions WIth Beautiful Soup HTTPError Not Defined

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2, http-error

I'm trying to write code so that it scrap stock symbols data into a csv file. However, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "company_data_v3.py", line 23, in <module>
    page = urllib2.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s="+newsymbolslist[i] +"%20Key%20Statistics").read()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

I have tried this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600707/python-exception-not-recognized-how-to-handle-with-except) but it has not worked which imports urlib2 HTTPError into the program. (It seems redundant to do that since I already have the module imported.

The symbols.txt file has stock symbols. Here is the code that I am using:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re
import urllib
from urllib2 import HTTPError
# import modules

symbolfile = open("symbols.txt")
symbolslist = symbolfile.read()
newsymbolslist = symbolslist.split("\n")

i = 0

f = csv.writer(open("pe_ratio.csv","wb"))
# short cut to write

f.writerow(["Name","PE","Revenue % Quarterly","ROA% YOY","Operating Cashflow","Debt to Equity"])
#first write row statement

# define name_company as the following
while i<len(newsymbolslist):
    page = urllib2.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s="+newsymbolslist[i] +"%20Key%20Statistics").read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    name_company = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "title"}) 
    for name in name_company: #add multiple iterations?        
        all_data = soup.findAll('td', "yfnc_tabledata1")
        stock_name = name.find('h2').string #find company's name in name_company with h2 tag
        try:    
            f.writerow([stock_name, all_data[2].getText(),all_data[17].getText(),all_data[13].getText(), all_data[29].getText(),all_data[26].getText()]) #write down PE data
        except (IndexError, urllib2.HTTPError) as e:
            pass
        i+=1
```

Do I need to define the error more specifically? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are catching the exception in the wrong location. The `urlopen()` call throws the exception, as shown by the first lines of your traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "company_data_v3.py", line 23, in <module>
    page = urllib2.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s="+newsymbolslist[i] +"%20Key%20Statistics").read()
```

Catch it there:

```
while i<len(newsymbolslist):
    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s="+newsymbolslist[i] +"%20Key%20Statistics").read()
    except urllib2.HTTPError:
        continue
```

Comment: I try the code suggestion you gave and I get an indentation error. I know it is a simple fix. How do I modify the soup and name_company variables? Should I throw them in the for loop?

Comment: The rest, from `soup = ` onwards, follows at the same indentation level it is at now in your code, so spaced to match the `try:` statement.