# How to continue looping after a module defined exception in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I loop though a list of currencies in order to download price series from an API and it happens that some of them are not supported so that it raises a module defined exception class : `ExchangeError: This currency pair is not supported`.

When it occurs I would like to continue the loop to the next currency but for some reason I'm unable to handle the module exception.

Here is an example that works fine with a built-in exception :

```
f = [1,2,3,4,'A',5]

def foo(nb):
    return nb /2

for i in f :

    try:
        print(foo(i))

    except TypeError :
        continue
```

As expected it returns :

```
0.5
1
1.5
2
2.5
```

But as soon as it is a module (or user defined) exception it throws an error saying the exception is not defined :

```
@retry(wait_exponential_multiplier=1000, wait_exponential_max=10000)
def apiFetchOHLC(obj, currency, timeframe, option):

    ohlcv = obj().fetch_ohlcv(currency, timeframe, since = option)
    return ohlc


for c in currencies_list :
    ...
    try :        
        # Download data
        ohlc = apiFetchOHLC(obj, c, tf, maxCandlesLimit)

    # except : # works fine
    except ExchangeError : # doesn't work
        print("Oops!  That was no valid currency.  Continue...")
        continue
```

This is the error I get when I run the loop :

```
except ExchangeError:    
NameError: name 'ExchangeError' is not defined
```

To make it works I need to remove the exception type `ExchangeError` but to me it is not a workaround because it will continue the loop whatever the exception is, and sometimes I need to retry the download.

How can I achieve this with `try` and `except` or with the `retrying` package ? ([link](https://pypi.org/project/retrying/))

Comment: Weird, you're code should work. Coul you provide some data so we can test it?

Comment: To make it work I need to remove the exception type `ExchangeError` inside the loop like this `except :` instead of `except ExchangeError :`. Loop is running at the moment but I'll try to provide data asap.

Comment: @Mathieu I edited the question after I better identify the problem. It seems related with the module exception `ExchangeError` which is not defined inside the loop, whereas another example with a built-in exception works fine.

Comment: @Florent did you create custom exception to handle this? Can you please add where you defined `ExchangeError` ?

Comment: @ManojJadhav I use a package with pre-defined class exceptions, in the example it's called with `obj().fetch_ohlcv()`

Comment: I think I get it, just need to give the full name space of the exception class I want to catch: `except ccxt.ExchangeError:` as answered is this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600707/nameerror-global-name-httperror-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After identifying the problem better I have found that I needed to give the full name space of the exception class I want to catch:

```
for c in currencies_list :
    ...
    try :        
        # Download data
        ohlc = apiFetchOHLC(obj, c, tf, maxCandlesLimit)

    except ccxt.ExchangeError : 
        print("Oops!  That was no valid currency.  Continue...")
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(count):
    try:
        while(count < 10):
            if(count%2 == 1):
                raise Exception()
            print(count)
            count = count+1
    except:
        print( str(count) + ' -> Exception')
        foo(count+1)

foo(2)
```

Whenever an exception occurs in a try block, handle it in except block as follows -

1. To continue the process you are doing in `try` block, you should reach the `try` block from an `except` block - keep the `try` block in a `function`, name it `foo`, so that you could call it from the `except` block
2. To continue from the next iteration, you need to know the previous iteration where the exception has been raised - pass an argument to that function